# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Flash' not found in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I tried lot,googling even took help from laracast.com/discuss but could not solve the issue. why the session flash is not working? please drop your suggestion. Here is my code of all_controll.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use App\Quotation;
use App\Model\students;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Session;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


class all_control extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
    public function insert_students(Request $request)
    {
        $std = new students();
        $std->name = $request->input('name');
        $std->email = $request->input('email');
        $std->save();
        return redirect('/index');
    }
    public function getform()
    {
        return view('form');
    }
    public function postform()
    {
        $roll = Input::get('roll');
        $ct_number = Input::get('ct');
        DB::table('test')->insert(array(
            'name'  =>  $roll,
            'age'   =>  $ct_number
        ));
        Flash :: Session ("key",
            "You have done successfully!!!!");
        //Session::flash('message','You have done successfully!!!!');
        return Redirect::route('getform');
        //return redirect('/index');
    }
}
```

and my form.blade.php code is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name=description content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <h3>
            <?php
            if(Session::has('key')){
                echo Session::get('key');
            }
            ?>
        </h3>

        <form action="{{ URL::route('postform') }}" method="post" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <legend>Form Title</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="roll" id="roll" placeholder="Input...">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Marks of Physisc CT</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ct" id="ct" placeholder="Input...">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Hit the Button</button>
        </form>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Flash :: Session ("key",
            "You have done successfully!!!!");

what are you trying to here actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built in `redirect()` [helper which will flash the data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) to the session by using `->with()`.

```
public function postform(Request $request)
    {
        $roll = $request->roll;
        $ct_number = $request->ct;
        DB::table('test')->insert([
            'name'  =>  $roll,
            'age'   =>  $ct_number
        ]);
        return redirect('index')->with('key', 'You have done successfully');
    }
```

SIDENOTE:

Inject `Request` into your method and use it instead of `Input`. `Input` was used in laravel 4 while injecting the `Request` class is the recommended way in laravel 5.1

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced same issue with you.

My solution is to include `use Flash;` on top of the controller that you wanted to use the Laracasts Flash plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('success_msg', 'Post deleted successfully');

Here Success_msg is used to display msg on redirected page.